# Extending the out of the box User model in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5, eloquent

First off -- forgive the ignorance, I'm new to Laravel. :)

I'm playing around in Laravel and am running into an issue when extending the out of the box `User` model. I'd like to implement a basic concept of roles that should be simply represented as a property of the `User`.

I've created the default User model and authentication:

> artisan make:auth

From there, that produced:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];  
}
```

I've also created a UseRoles model and attempted to create the relationship between the two:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class UserRoles extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'user_roles';

    public function User()
    {
        $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

And over in the `User` model I added:

```
public function Roles()
{
    $this->hasMany('App\UserRoles', 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

Lastly, I ran the migration scripts and started the server, hit localhost and logged in using the default bootstrapped auth.

What I expect to see is a collection of Roles off of the User model, but I do not. A print_r shows the default user model with no additional properties.

Is there something obvious that I'm overlooking?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

The `Roles()` method is only a method defining the relation between you `User` model and the `UserRoles` model. In fact it returns an instance of a `Relation` object on which you can play with

There isn't a property with the roles stored in the `User` model: you should call `Auth::user()->Roles()->get()` to make a query on the DB and get back a `Collection` of `UserRoles`

Alternatively, you can access the collection by using the dynamic property `Auth::user()->Roles;` that will lazy-load the relation from the DB

Comment: Thanks for the info -- exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer to your question but in both `Roles()` ans `User()` you need to return those relations `return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id', 'id');`